# How to add element directly to the child of custom module in qml?

Tags: qt, qml

How to add element directly to the child of custom module in qml?
There are three Rectangle(rect1/rect2/rect3) below as the content of ScrollView

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

ScrollView {
    property var content

    clip: true
    ScrollBar.vertical.policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
    Rectangle {
        width:  parent.width
        height: c.height
        implicitHeight: c.height

        Column {
            id: c
            spacing: 20
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

            // Contents

            Rectangle{
                id: rect1
                width: 100
                height: 200
                color: "#ffff00"
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            }

            Rectangle{
                id: rect2
                width: 100
                height: 200
                color: "#000000"
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            }


            Rectangle{
                id: rect3
                width: 100
                height: 200
                color: "#00ffff"
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            }
        }
    }

}
```

But each time writing to the above is more complicated
I want to encapsulate the above code into MyScrollView.qml module

I want to use it like this

```
MyScrollView {
    Rectangle {
        id: rect1
        width: 100
        height: 200
        color: "#ffff00"
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: rect2
        width: 100
        height: 200
        color: "#000000"
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: rect3
        width: 100
        height: 200
        color: "#00ffff"
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
   }
}
```

Is it possible for qml to do this? If not, how to write the most elegant?

Comment: can you please elaborate what do you mean saying "add element directly to the child"? What exactly do you want to do? Some code example?

Answer (score 2):

You could achive this using different approaches, for example there is [Qt.createComponent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html) for dynamic object creations on the fly

or you can assign [alias property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#property-aliases) to reference some internal central object to assign Items

Or you can use [Loader](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html) to load components.

I'll show example based on your wishes in topic :)

create **MyScrollView.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

ScrollView {
    property list<Item> content_list

    clip: true
    ScrollBar.vertical.policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn

    Component.onCompleted:
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < content_list.length; i++)
        {
            content_list[i].parent = c;
        }
    }

    Rectangle
    {
        width:  parent.width
        height: c.height
        implicitHeight: c.height

        Column
        {
            id: c
            spacing: 20
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        }
    }
}
```

And somewhere use it like so:

```
MyScrollView{content_list: [
                Rectangle {
                        id: rect1
                        width: 100
                        height: 200
                        color: "#ffff00"
                        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                    },

                    Rectangle {
                        id: rect2
                        width: 100
                        height: 200
                        color: "#000000"
                        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                    },

                    Rectangle {
                        id: rect3
                        width: 100
                        height: 200
                        color: "#00ffff"
                        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                   }
            ]}
```